# OAUTH access_token TTL

Tags: oauth-2.0

I've got an OAUTH2 Authentication Server which set a default TTL (3600s) for every new acccess_token.

But in my opinion the access_token TTL should be different for every Resource Server.
Like for a JavaScript Webinterface it should be 3600s, for an Android App it could be one month.

Who decides how long the access_token TTL should be?
Should the GET access_token request from the Client request a custom TTL?
Should the TTL for every Resource be defined in the Service Configuration (along with client_id, client_secret, App Description, ...) on the Authentication server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Authorization Server that issues the token is responsible for assigning an expiry time to it. There's no standardized authorization request parameter that the client can use to indicate the preferred TTL. The Authorization Server decides based on a policy that may be based on the client identifier and the associated/configured "permissions" or "trust", parameters available in the Authorization Request (e.g. `scope`) and other contextual data like HTTP request parameters, time of the day etc.